# Unexpected behavior in SQLite query using random()

Tags: sqlite, function, random, deterministic

```
SELECT random() as r from my_tbl where r < 0 LIMIT 10
```

returns 10 numbers, but some are positive, which is not what I'd expect.  Is this a bug in SQLite?

Comment: Just ran the query and I see what you mean! Most unexpected indeed. Most devs probably haven't run into this because random is more often used like 'SELECT * FROM my_tbl ORDER BY random() LIMIT 10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions in the SELECT clause are the *output* of the query, so they are computed *after* the rows have been filtered.
Therefore, the SQL standard forbids using output aliases (such as `r`) in any other clause of the query.

SQLite allows it anyway, but the effects are not always what you intend.
`AS` just *renames* an output column (i.e., it gives a short name to an expression), so when you use such an alias in the WHERE clause, what you get is not the *value* of the output column, but a copy of the original *expression*. The effect is the same as:

```
SELECT random() FROM my_tbl WHERE random() < 0 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a workaround that would allow me to select the numbers generated by the query that are negative?

Comment: Yes; but what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have a UDF which takes in a city as a string and returns the current temperature of that city.  A user of my DB is writing queries that look for cities with negative temperatures.  But what's happening is the temperature of a city is negative on the first call to my UDF, but on the second call to it, the temperature is positive.  The effect is that the user sees results that are inconsistent with the query criteria (pos. temps).  Even if the temperature is no longer negative, the user would appreciate either seeing the negative temperature in the result or not seeing the result row at all.

Comment: So the problem is that changing temperatures are changing? The best way to handle that would be to create a temporary table with a snapshot of the data.